# What is the best way to build recurring events in Slack using modals?

Tags: modal-dialog, slack, slack-api, slack-dialog

I'm trying to build a recurring event for my Slack app using modals. Though I handled weekly recurring events, I am not sure how to handle monthly recurring events - say, Monthly on 6th, Monthly every first Tuesday, Monthly every second Tuesday, etc.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried

Comment: This is a very broad question. The answer for recurring events almost always is some form of CRON, but the implementation will vary depending on your system and programming language. Please specify more details.

Comment: I'm trying to build recurring events for a Slack APIs using modals

Comment: Thanks. but you did not provide any new information. Anyways, here is a link to a free web cron services that you can use to trigger your services at periodic intervals. https://cron-job.org/en/